# IndexError: list index out of range when read LUNA16

Tags: python

When I tried to read the luna dataset,there's the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_preprocess.py", line 57, in <module>
    save_preprocessed_data()
  File "run_preprocess.py", line 48, in save_preprocessed_data
    ct = CTScan(seriesuid=series_id, centers=tp_co, radii=radii, clazz=0)
  File "C:\Luna16-master\prepare\_classes.py", line 14, in __init__
    path = glob(f'''{RESOURCES_PATH} /*/{seriesuid}.mhd''')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How to solve it?
Thanks in advance.
The code is:

```
class CTScan(object):
def __init__(self, seriesuid, centers, radii, clazz):
    self._seriesuid = seriesuid
    self._centers = centers
    path = glob(f'''{RESOURCES_PATH} /*/{seriesuid}.mhd''')[0]
    # path = paths[0]
    self._ds = sitk.ReadImage(path)
    self._spacing = np.array(list(reversed(self._ds.GetSpacing())))
    self._origin = np.array(list(reversed(self._ds.GetOrigin())))
    self._image = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(self._ds)
    self._radii = radii
    self._clazz = clazz
    self._mask = None
```

Comment: check the output of this `glob(f'''{RESOURCES_PATH} /*/{seriesuid}.mhd''')`, I think it returns an empty list `[]`.

Comment: @AcaNg Yes it is empty list, but it shouldn't be empty...